# How to style QTableView CSS

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, qtableview

What would be a correct CSS syntax to style a `QTableView` items `checkboxes`? Since QCheckBox is a part of QTableView it is tricky to get to the checkbox with CSS...

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

appStyle="""

QTableView
{
    alternate-background-color: #1F1F1F;
    background-color: gray;
    gridline-color: gray;
    color: gray;
}
QTableView::item 
{   
    color: white;        
}

QTableView::item:focus
{   
    color: gray;
    background: #0063cd;            
}        
QTableView::item:selected
{   
    color: gray;
    background: #0063cd;            
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked, QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #323232;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 5px;
}

"""
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_001','Item_002','Item_003']
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)      
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1
    def flags (self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        if role==Qt.DisplayRole:    return QVariant(self.items[index.row()])             
        elif role == Qt.CheckStateRole:   return QVariant(Qt.Checked)
        else:            return QVariant()

class MyWindow(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args):        
        QTableView.__init__(self, *args)
        tableModel=Model(self)
        self.setModel(tableModel)
        self.setStyleSheet(appStyle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use `QTableView QCheckBox::indicator:checked{ /*...*/ }` selector. Note, this will work only in you have real checkbox widgets. I propose you to use delegates for that.

Comment: I  am using the checkboxes as result of using `if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:   return QVariant(Qt.Checked)` in sourceModel's `data()` method. Let me see if that would still work... Thanks for an idea!

Comment: Unfortunately `QTableView QCheckBox::indicator:checked{...)` doesn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine its a similar sector to the `QCheckBox::indicator`, `QListView::indicator`, `QTreeView::indicator`.... try:

```
QTableView::indicator:checked {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: #323232;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 5px;
}
```